# What is this bitwise OR doing in this weird array key construct?

Tags: php

Can someone explain to me what this means?? I have never seen this construct - taken from the [Prestashop doc](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-Creatingthemodule%27sbackofficetab%2Canditsclass)

```
foreach ( $languages as $language )
{
  echo '<div id="test_' . $language['id_lang'|'id_lang'] .... // <-- What the??
  // ... 
}
```

$language contains the following keys:

```
Array
(
    [id_lang] => 1
    [name] => English (English)
    // and others... 
)
```

The result is that it takes the value of $language["id_lang"] - 1. But I don't understand the syntax and can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: `'id_lang'|'id_lang' === 'id_lang'`, so I'm not really sure why they are doing that…

Comment: I think they are trying to mask bits from the ID as only matching 0 bits will result in 0.

Comment: Oh prestashop, you so silly ...

Comment: You all had the same answer, which confirmed my suspicions. Thanks - I'm giving points to Botond for finding my new favorite word - "idempotence" - and because he needed the rep points more.

Comment: Maybe originally there were different things either side of the `|` that were there for a reason, and then one was changed to `id_lang`, and the changer did not notice that the other one also had that value.

Comment: Every explained how this is a pointless operation and that the author (or the re-writer as the case may be) has no idea what they were doing. But nobody has a theory for how this possibly could have happened? I'm intrigued. I spent a while trying to think of how exactly this construction could have come to be and none of the ideas I've had seem plausible.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This `php -a` session shows that it's totally meaningless:

```
php > $value = 'something'|'something';
php > echo $value;
something
php > $arr = array('abc' => 1, 'def' => 2);
php > echo $arr['abc'|'abc'];
1
php > echo $arr['def'|'def'];
2
```

Basically, if you "bitwise or" anything by itself, you get the original value. This property is called **idempotence** in mathematics. For further info, read:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR

Honestly, the original author of that code had no idea what they were doing.

Comment: Thanks for the research. I rather like the ring of "idempotence" - it seems fitting for the construct.

Comment: I like it too. One of my favorite useless words I learned in college :)

Comment: Quote from php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php): Be aware of data type conversions. If both the left-hand and right-hand parameters are strings, the bitwise operator will operate on the characters' ASCII values.

Comment: could this test be used to test encoding type? as in if one of the strings where utf 8 and one utf 16, then the result wouldn't match the first... of course if it were hard coded in a file it wouldn't make much sense...

Comment: @GradyPlayer: I'm not an expert in character encodings but I'm pretty sure there are more standard, less hackish ways to determine the encoding.

Comment: but it would be a very good test to see if the encoding mattered ... Mac Roman vs UTF8, not arguing out of context that it is good code, just dont like to see "Honestly, the original author of that code had no idea what they were doing."

Comment: @GradyPlayer No you can't, at least not reliably. Different encodings use different numbers of bytes for a character, depending on how many code points the encoding has. Doing a bitwise or on a 4 byte encoded character and a 1 byte encoded character might well return the same character if the first byte matches, but that doesn't necessarily mean they have the same encoding.

Comment: well if the binary data is the same then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @GradyPlayer There are varying numbers of bits (that's the binary data). The smallest number of bits get operated on, but simply having those match is not a guarantee that the rest of the bits are identical.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: testing the encoding of two *string literals*? How on Earth does that make sense? I am absolutely 100% sure the original author really didn't know what they were doing.

Comment: @Botond The best explanation is that they copy/pasted it from somewhere where it is actually useful. Maybe there was a variable bitwise a constant for some magic operation that needed to be done and they thought "hey i dont have to use a variable, ill just hard code both values!". Even if that's still silly, it's what most likely happened... I guess.

Answer (score 14):

What that does is use the bitwise operator on the ASCII values of the characters in the string "id_lang", although why they are doing this is beyond me, since the result is always going to be the same.

To elaborate a little bit, let's say (for convenience) that we're using ASCII, where each character is encoded as a single byte. Let's look at what happens when it does the comparison for the binary representation of the first character (i is `105`, which in binary is `01101001`):

```
   "i": 01101001
OR "i": 01101001
      ___________
      = 01101001
      = "i"
```

`0|0` is 0, `1|1` is 1, so inevitably all bits remain unchanged.

Comment: To be more pedantic: it's bitwise or-ing the *byte values* of the string, which depends on however it happens to be encoded. Yes, in practice that's pretty much going to be the "ASCII values"... :)

Comment: @deceze Wouldn't that be *bit values*? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Same thing, really. 1 byte is 8 bits, and ASCII characters are typically expressed as byte values...

Answer (score 9):

It's not doing anything, strangely enough.

```
var_dump('id_lang'|'id_lang');
#=> string(7) "id_lang"
```

http://ideone.com/zXdRMO

Even if it *was* doing something, using a bitwise operator on a string-based array key certainly feels like code smell to me.